# ASP.MVC 3 Installation error

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm installing ASP.NET MVC 3 Beta and this thing comes out :

**This product requires Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages 1.0. Please install the missing component, then try to install this product again.**

What the hell? I'm using MVC 2 just fine. Should I go and install asp web pages 1.0 and where do I get if from ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MVC 3 Beta download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0abac7a3-b302-4644-bd43-febf300b2c51&displaylang=en) contains download links for both the MVC 3 Beta installer (named AspNetMVC3Setup.exe) and the Web Pages installer (AspNetWebPages.msi).

Or you can use the following link to install everything automatically using WebPI: http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=MVC3

Comment: Oh.. I didn't even see that. Thx a lot. You've saved me log of time!

Comment: Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages is the official name for the Razor view engine.  Separately packaged so that other .Net and Web Matrix environments can also use it

Comment: k. now I see it. coz in MVC 3 preview it all was in one pack and now it is a bit confusing.

Comment: Well, the Preview1 code was a bit of a hack in which we simply included the Razor sources in the MVC assembly. Now it is factored into a seperate project so that it can be used from both MVC and other types of applications, like WebMatrix or even console apps.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error even after manually installing the AspNetWebPages.msi file. It seems that the download is the wrong version for the MVC3 Beta download.

I took the second option and intalled the Web Platform Installer from http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=MVC3. This installed MVC 3 and also installed the correct Web Pages dependency, which turned out to be Web Pages Beta 2.

The Web Platform Installer also lists a lot of other interesting packages which you might find hard to locate during normal IIS installation.